# Bundle Installer which records installation steps

Tags: installation, bundle

I need to know about the bundle installers which records steps for executable file similar to **Silent Install Builder**.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try http://www.advancedinstaller.com/. A bit pricy, but I think it has a setup capture module. Other than that there are several older and less functional capture tools that I don't have links to at the moment. Amd there isthe full blown [AdminStudio](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/application-packaging/adminstudio/).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. 
But I need bundle installer in which I can include multiple executable files and installer should record there execution steps.